# Dynamically generating image link

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how i can open a link dynamically.

Example:

http://www.google.com/20131006_E225_vid.png

and tomorrow it will be based on

http://www.google.com/20131007_E223_vid.png

so each time the date and the product changes.

So I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this by just making use of day to dynamically generate the next day with whatever product it has. because only date can be predicted and not the Product.

Comment: But those dates are not from today or tomorrow? You do want the url to have the date of today in it?

Comment: What have you tried? Seriously, do you have anything you've started with, maybe some markup you could share, or some semblance you've attempted to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
window.onload
```

To set the image. If your base path is always the same you make the function to run onload something along the lines of

```
function setImg(){
    var pic = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var d = new Date();
    var path = "http://example.com/" + d.getFullYear().toString() + d.getDate().toString() + d.getMonth().toString() + ".png";
    pic.src = path;
}
```

Comment: this is giving `2044` rather than `20132011`

Comment: Heh. It's adding the three integer values together, then concatenating them with the string.

Comment: How about if the product number changes dynamically i would still like to pass the date value and by default the remaining portion should pick up even though it changes dynamically. Is that achievable?

Comment: What do you mean it changes dynamically? Is there any logic to it?>

Comment: For anyone who arrives here later, these comments are no longer relevant as @A1rPun made the appropriate corrections for this to work properly.